# Acceptable and unacceptable number shifts in writing

Tags: style

Many writing handbooks say unnecessary number shifts should be avoided. But are all number shifts bad?
What about the following?

> 1. **Glass harps** haven’t entirely disappeared, though. You can still find some street musicians playing **them** to entertain large crowds. If you’re lucky enough to catch such a performance, sit back, relax, and enjoy the beautiful sounds of **this unusual instrument**.
> 2. **Glass harps** haven’t entirely disappeared, though. You can still find some street musicians playing **them** to entertain large crowds. If you’re lucky enough to catch such a performance, sit back, relax, and enjoy the beautiful sounds of **the instrument**.
> 3. **Glass harps** haven’t entirely disappeared, though. You can still find some street musicians playing **them** to entertain large crowds. If you’re lucky enough to catch such a performance, sit back, relax, and enjoy **its** beautiful sounds.

Comment: Already answered here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/200965/this-unusual-instrument-with-plural-antecedents/200967

Comment: No. That post didn't consider the alternatives.

Comment: Your question is about number concordance, which is very well explained in the answers and comments from the link above.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of another question on English Language Stack Exchange, which is answered there. The example sentence is identical. The only difference is the OP adds more singular alternatives, but the reasons for using plurals and then a singular are fully explained in the answers to the original post.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/200965/this-unusual-instrument-with-plural-antecedents/200967

Comment: Could you tell me how the comments there address the alternatives?

Comment: @Apollyon You use a singular because it agrees with "a performance" on "a harp". *"If you are lucky enough to catch such* ***a performance,*** *..."*. A singular performance, without any further qualifier, is presumed to be on ***one harp.*** There referring to that one harp, you use the singular possessive pronoun  ***"its"***. This is explained in one of the answers to the previous question. This is a duplicate; all your examples are singulars; "this instrument", "the instrument", "its sounds". You use the singular because you switched to "a [singular] performance".

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have no problem with the first two sentences, but I really don't like number 3 (and I expect that is one reason why the first sentence ends "this unusual instrument").